# Wrong output from jsp page

Tags: html, jsp

I have a jsp page given below

```
<%@page import="newpack.SendMailJavaToXsl07022013"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script language="javascript">
            <!--
            // <![CDATA[
            function Button1_onclick() {
            <%
                SendMailJavaToXsl07022013 oaa = new SendMailJavaToXsl07022013();
                oaa.mainClass();
                out.print("Sdasd");
                System.out.println( "In getDate() method" );
            %>
                }
                // ]]>
        </script>
</head>
<body>        
        <%=request.getParameter("key")%><br/>
        <input name="send mail" id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" onfocus="dfgdgf"/>
</body>
    </html>
```

I expect function Button1_onclick() execute only after clicking Button. But it execute when page loads, and never execute when Button click.
What is wrong in this code?

Comment: <% %> code is executed server side, so SendMailJava... is executed at rendering. This is not JavaScript, this is Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your `page source` after executing your `jsp page` then you will find that your method has no `JAVA CODE`.

**Page source snippet**

```
<script language="javascript">
    <!--
    // <![CDATA[
    function Button1_onclick() {

        }
        // ]]>
</script>
```

So i will suggest you that instead of running your code on client machine, send request from client to Server and then execute the `java code` on server, and then send back the response to client...
I hope this will help you...